# How do I "use up" items in Dragon Quest Builders 2?

Tags: dragon-quest-builders-2

I have an infinite number of certain items (like wood) and when I try to craft items out of wood, it no longer uses up any of the 1000's of wood that I've collected.  How do I use up all this wood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, you don't.

Just go to your inventory and destroy the items you don't want anymore.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  I don't think I can bring myself to do it!

Comment: Yeah me too. I kinda put a chest somewhere in the ground and fill it with unwanted stuff ... then forget about it.